# How do I read the output of a child process without blocking in Rust?

Tags: process, io, rust, blocking, pty

I'm making a small ncurses application in Rust that needs to communicate with a child process. I already have a prototype written in Common Lisp. I'm trying to rewrite it because CL uses a huge amount of memory for such a small tool.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to interact with the sub-process.

What I'm currently doing is roughly this:

1. Create the process:

   ```
   let mut program = match Command::new(command)
       .args(arguments)
       .stdin(Stdio::piped())
       .stdout(Stdio::piped())
       .stderr(Stdio::piped())
       .spawn()
   {
       Ok(child) => child,
       Err(_) => {
           println!("Cannot run program '{}'.", command);
           return;
       }
   };
   ```
2. Pass it to an infinite (until user exits) loop, which reads and handles input and listens for output like this (and writes it to the screen):

   ```
   fn listen_for_output(program: &mut Child, output_viewer: &TextViewer) {
       match program.stdout {
           Some(ref mut out) => {
               let mut buf_string = String::new();
               match out.read_to_string(&mut buf_string) {
                   Ok(_) => output_viewer.append_string(buf_string),
                   Err(_) => return,
               };
           }
           None => return,
       };
   }
   ```

The call to `read_to_string` however blocks the program until the process exits. From what I can see `read_to_end` and `read` also seem to block. If I try running something like `ls` which exits right away, it works, but with something that doesn't exit like `python` or `sbcl` it only continues once I kill the subprocess manually.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31577297/155423), I changed the code to use `BufReader`:

```
    fn listen_for_output(program: &mut Child, output_viewer: &TextViewer) {
        match program.stdout.as_mut() {
            Some(out) => {
                let buf_reader = BufReader::new(out);
                for line in buf_reader.lines() {
                    match line {
                        Ok(l) => {
                            output_viewer.append_string(l);
                        }
                        Err(_) => return,
                    };
                }
            }
            None => return,
        }
    }
```

However, the problem still remains the same. It will read all lines that are available, and then block. Since the tool is supposed to work with any program, there is no way to guess out when the output will end, before trying to read. There doesn't appear to be a way to set a timeout for `BufReader` either.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Streams are *blocking* by default. TCP/IP streams, filesystem streams, pipe streams, they are all blocking. When you tell a stream to give you a chunk of bytes it will stop and wait till it has the given amout of bytes or till something else happens (an [interrupt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249577/interrupting-blocked-read), an end of stream, an error).

The operating systems are eager to return the data to the reading process, so if all you want is to wait for the next line and handle it as soon as it comes in then the method suggested by Shepmaster in [Unable to pipe to or from spawned child process more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31576555/unable-to-pipe-to-or-from-spawned-child-process-more-than-once/31577297#31577297) (and also in his answer here) works.
Though in theory it doesn't have to work, because an operating system is allowed to make the `BufReader` wait for more data in `read`, but in practice the operating systems prefer the early "short reads" to waiting.

This simple `BufReader`-based approach becomes even more dangerous when you need to handle multiple streams (like the `stdout` and `stderr` of a child process) or multiple processes. For example, `BufReader`-based approach might deadlock when a child process waits for you to drain its `stderr` pipe while your process is blocked waiting on it's empty `stdout`.

Similarly, you can't use `BufReader` when you don't want your program to wait on the child process indefinitely. Maybe you want to display a progress bar or a timer while the child is still working and gives you no output.

You can't use `BufReader`-based approach if your operating system happens not to be eager in returning the data to the process (prefers "full reads" to "short reads") because in that case a few last lines printed by the child process might end up in a gray zone: the operating system got them, but they're not large enough to fill the `BufReader`'s buffer.

`BufReader` is limited to what the `Read` interface allows it to do with the stream, it's no less blocking than the underlying stream is. In order to be efficient it will [read](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.read) the input in chunks, telling the operating system to fill as much of its buffer as it has available.

You might be wondering why reading data in chunks is so important here, why can't the `BufReader` just read the data byte by byte. The problem is that to read the data from a stream we need the operating system's help. On the other hand, we are not the operating system, we work isolated from it, so as not to mess with it if something goes wrong with our process. So in order to call to the operating system there needs to be a transition to "kernel mode" which might also incur a "context switch". That is why calling the operating system to read every single byte is expensive. We want as few OS calls as possible and so we get the stream data in batches.

To wait on a stream without blocking you'd need a *non-blocking stream*. MIO [promises to have the required non-blocking stream support for pipes](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/2nka2k/interactive_pipe_reading/cmfbe5w), most probably with [PipeReader](http://rustdoc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mio/v0.5.x/mio/unix/struct.PipeReader.html), but I haven't checked it out so far.

The non-blocking nature of a stream should make it possible to read data in chunks regardless of whether the operating system prefers the "short reads" or not. Because non-blocking stream never blocks. If there is no data in the stream it simply tells you so.

In the absense of a non-blocking stream you'll have to resort to spawning threads so that the blocking reads would be performed in a separate thread and thus won't block your primary thread. You might also want to read the stream byte by byte in order to react to the line separator immediately in case the operating system does not prefer the "short reads". Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/ArtemGr/db40ae04b431a95f2b78.

P.S. Here's an example of a function that allows to monitor the standard output of a program via a shared vector of bytes:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

/// Pipe streams are blocking, we need separate threads to monitor them without blocking the primary thread.
fn child_stream_to_vec<R>(mut stream: R) -> Arc<Mutex<Vec<u8>>>
where
    R: Read + Send + 'static,
{
    let out = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let vec = out.clone();
    thread::Builder::new()
        .name("child_stream_to_vec".into())
        .spawn(move || loop {
            let mut buf = [0];
            match stream.read(&mut buf) {
                Err(err) => {
                    println!("{}] Error reading from stream: {}", line!(), err);
                    break;
                }
                Ok(got) => {
                    if got == 0 {
                        break;
                    } else if got == 1 {
                        vec.lock().expect("!lock").push(buf[0])
                    } else {
                        println!("{}] Unexpected number of bytes: {}", line!(), got);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .expect("!thread");
    out
}

fn main() {
    let mut cat = Command::new("cat")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("!cat");

    let out = child_stream_to_vec(cat.stdout.take().expect("!stdout"));
    let err = child_stream_to_vec(cat.stderr.take().expect("!stderr"));
    let mut stdin = match cat.stdin.take() {
        Some(stdin) => stdin,
        None => panic!("!stdin"),
    };
}
```

With a couple of helpers I'm using it to control an SSH session:

```
try_s! (stdin.write_all (b"echo hello world\n"));
try_s! (wait_forˢ (&out, 0.1, 9., |s| s == "hello world\n"));
```

P.S. Note that `await` on a [read](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.6.5/async_std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read) call in async-std is blocking as well. It's just instead of blocking a system thread it only blocks a chain of futures (a stack-less green thread essentially). The [poll_read](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.6.5/async_std/io/trait.Read.html#tymethod.poll_read) is the non-blocking interface. In [async-std#499](https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/issues/499#issuecomment-614878693) I've asked the developers whether there's a short read guarantee from these APIs.

P.S. There might be [a similar concern in Nom](https://github.com/Geal/nom/issues/1145#issuecomment-678788326): "*we would want to tell the IO side to refill according to the parser's result (Incomplete or not)*"

P.S. Might be interesting to see how stream reading is implemented in crossterm. For Windows, in [poll.rs](https://github.com/crossterm-rs/crossterm/blob/58f580eaad4e80ccb8a09541b760a329971bb4bc/src/event/sys/windows/poll.rs), they are using the native [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects). In [unix.rs](https://github.com/crossterm-rs/crossterm/blob/b31782249e3ef1c2e5d8f2f668763fddb2e0a060/src/event/source/unix.rs) they are using mio `poll`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. I'll look into MIO, and if that doesn't work out, then I'll use separate threads.

Answer (score 17):

## Tokio's `Command`

Here is an example of using [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) 0.2:

```
use std::process::Stdio;
use futures::StreamExt; // 0.3.1
use tokio::{io::BufReader, prelude::*, process::Command}; // 0.2.4, features = ["full"]

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("/tmp/slow.bash")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped()) // Can do the same for stderr
        .spawn()
        .expect("cannot spawn");

    let stdout = cmd.stdout().take().expect("no stdout");
    // Can do the same for stderr

    // To print out each line
    // BufReader::new(stdout)
    //     .lines()
    //     .for_each(|s| async move { println!("> {:?}", s) })
    //     .await;

    // To print out each line *and* collect it all into a Vec
    let result: Vec<_> = BufReader::new(stdout)
        .lines()
        .inspect(|s| println!("> {:?}", s))
        .collect()
        .await;

    println!("All the lines: {:?}", result);
}
```

## Tokio-Threadpool

Here is an example of using [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) 0.1 and [tokio-threadpool](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-threadpool). We start the process in a thread using the [`blocking`](https://docs.rs/tokio-threadpool/0.1.13/tokio_threadpool/fn.blocking.html) function. We convert that to a stream with [`stream::poll_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.26/futures/stream/fn.poll_fn.html)

```
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use tokio::{prelude::*, runtime::Runtime}; // 0.1.18
use tokio_threadpool; // 0.1.13

fn stream_command_output(
    mut command: Command,
) -> impl Stream<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = tokio_threadpool::BlockingError> {
    // Ensure that the output is available to read from and start the process
    let mut child = command
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("cannot spawn");
    let mut stdout = child.stdout.take().expect("no stdout");

    // Create a stream of data
    stream::poll_fn(move || {
        // Perform blocking IO
        tokio_threadpool::blocking(|| {
            // Allocate some space to store anything read
            let mut data = vec![0; 128];
            // Read 1-128 bytes of data
            let n_bytes_read = stdout.read(&mut data).expect("cannot read");

            if n_bytes_read == 0 {
                // Stdout is done
                None
            } else {
                // Only return as many bytes as we read
                data.truncate(n_bytes_read);
                Some(data)
            }
        })
    })
}

fn main() {
    let output_stream = stream_command_output(Command::new("/tmp/slow.bash"));

    let mut runtime = Runtime::new().expect("Unable to start the runtime");

    let result = runtime.block_on({
        output_stream
            .map(|d| String::from_utf8(d).expect("Not UTF-8"))
            .fold(Vec::new(), |mut v, s| {
                print!("> {}", s);
                v.push(s);
                Ok(v)
            })
    });

    println!("All the lines: {:?}", result);
}
```

There's numerous possible tradeoffs that can be made here. For example, always allocating 128 bytes isn't ideal, but it's simple to implement.

## Support

For reference, here's **slow.bash**:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eu

val=0

while [[ $val -lt 10 ]]; do
    echo $val
    val=$(($val + 1))
    sleep 1
done
```

See also:

- [How do I synchronously return a value calculated in an asynchronous Future in stable Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52521201/155423)

Comment: The "Tokio's Command" portion of this answer appears to be outdated, as I cannot get it working in my project.

Answer (score 2):

If Unix support is sufficient, you can also make the two output streams as non-blocking and poll over them as you would do it on `TcpStream` with the `set_nonblocking` function.

The `ChildStdout` and `ChildStderr` returned by the Command spawn are `Stdio` (and contain a file descriptor), you can modify directly the read behavior of these handle to make it non-blocking.

Based on the work of [jcreekmore/timeout-readwrite-rs](https://github.com/jcreekmore/timeout-readwrite-rs) and [anowell/nonblock-rs](https://github.com/anowell/nonblock-rs), I use this wrapper to modify the stream handles:

```rust
extern crate libc;
use std::io::Read;
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
use libc::{F_GETFL, F_SETFL, fcntl, O_NONBLOCK};

fn set_nonblocking<H>(handle: &H, nonblocking: bool) -> std::io::Result<()>
where
    H: Read + AsRawFd,
{
    let fd = handle.as_raw_fd();
    let flags = unsafe { fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0) };
    if flags < 0 {
        return Err(std::io::Error::last_os_error());
    }
    let flags = if nonblocking{
        flags | O_NONBLOCK
    } else {
        flags & !O_NONBLOCK
    };
    let res = unsafe { fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags) };
    if res != 0 {
        return Err(std::io::Error::last_os_error());
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

You can manage the two streams as any other non-blocking stream. The following example is based on the [polling](https://crates.io/crates/polling) crate which makes really easy to handle read event and `BufReader` for line reading:

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::thread;
extern crate polling;
use polling::{Event, Poller};

fn main() -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let path = PathBuf::from("./worker.sh").canonicalize()?;

    let mut child = Command::new(path)
        .stdin(Stdio::null())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .expect("Failed to start worker");

    let handle = thread::spawn({
        let stdout = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
        set_nonblocking(&stdout, true)?;
        let mut reader_out = BufReader::new(stdout);

        let stderr = child.stderr.take().unwrap();
        set_nonblocking(&stderr, true)?;
        let mut reader_err = BufReader::new(stderr);

        move || {
            let key_out = 1;
            let key_err = 2;
            let mut out_closed = false;
            let mut err_closed = false;

            let poller = Poller::new().unwrap();
            poller.add(reader_out.get_ref(), Event::readable(key_out)).unwrap();
            poller.add(reader_err.get_ref(), Event::readable(key_err)).unwrap();

            let mut line = String::new();
            let mut events = Vec::new();
            loop {
                // Wait for at least one I/O event.
                events.clear();
                poller.wait(&mut events, None).unwrap();

                for ev in &events {
                    // stdout is ready for reading
                    if ev.key == key_out {
                        let len = match reader_out.read_line(&mut line) {
                            Ok(len) => len,
                            Err(e) => {
                                println!("stdout read returned error: {}", e);
                                0
                            }
                        };
                        if len == 0 {
                            println!("stdout closed (len is null)");
                            out_closed = true;
                            poller.delete(reader_out.get_ref()).unwrap();
                        } else {
                            print!("[STDOUT] {}", line);
                            line.clear();
                            // reload the poller
                            poller.modify(reader_out.get_ref(), Event::readable(key_out)).unwrap();
                        }
                    }

                    // stderr is ready for reading
                    if ev.key == key_err {
                        let len = match reader_err.read_line(&mut line) {
                            Ok(len) => len,
                            Err(e) => {
                                println!("stderr read returned error: {}", e);
                                0
                            }
                        };
                        if len == 0 {
                            println!("stderr closed (len is null)");
                            err_closed = true;
                            poller.delete(reader_err.get_ref()).unwrap();
                        } else {
                            print!("[STDERR] {}", line);
                            line.clear();
                            // reload the poller
                            poller.modify(reader_err.get_ref(), Event::readable(key_err)).unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if out_closed && err_closed {
                    println!("Stream closed, exiting process thread");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    handle.join().unwrap();
    Ok(())
}
```

Additionally, used with a wrapper over an EventFd, it becomes possible to easily stop the process from another thread without blocking nor active polling and uses and only a single thread.

**EDIT:** It seems the polling crate sets automatically the polled handles in non-blocking mode following my tests. The set_nonblocking function is still useful in case you want to directly use the nix::poll object.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered enough use-cases where it was useful to interact with a subprocess over line-delimited text that I wrote a crate for it, [interactive_process](https://crates.io/crates/interactive_process).

I expect the original problem has long since been solved, but I thought it might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem while writing a GUI. To solve this, I used a thread for receiving output from child process. This approach prevents blocking main thread. but this approach requires the child process to have a quit command or terminated by himself.

```
fn main() {
    let mut stdin = comminucate("../mybin".to_string());
    stdin.write_all("some commands".as_bytes()).unwrap();
    stdin.write_all("quit".as_bytes()).unwrap();
}

pub fn comminucate(path: String) -> ChildStdin {
    let mut child = Command::new(path)
                    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
                    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                    .spawn()
                    .unwrap();
    
    let stdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();
    let stdout = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
    
    thread::spawn(move || {
        let reader = BufReader::new(stdout);
        /* it waits for new output */
        for line in reader.lines() {
            let output = line.unwrap();
            if output == "something1" {  /* do something */  }
            if output == "something2" {  /* do something */  }
        }
    });
    return stdin;
}
```