# How can I use Tokio to trigger a function every period or interval in seconds?

Tags: loops, rust, intervals, rust-tokio

In Node.js I can set the interval that a certain event should be triggered,

```js
function intervalFunc() {
  console.log('whelp, triggered again!');
}

setInterval(intervalFunc, 1500);
```

However the interface for Tokio's [interval](https://docs.rs/tokio/*/tokio/time/fn.interval.html) is a bit more complex. It seems to be a something to do with a much more literal definition of an interval, and rather than calling a function at an interval, it simply stalls the thread until the time passes (with `.await`).

Is there a primitive in Tokio that calls a function *"every x seconds"* or the like? If not, is there an idiom that has emerged to do this?

I only need to run one function on a recurring interval... I don't care about other threads either. It's just one function on Tokio's event loop.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Spawn a Tokio task](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.3.0/tokio/fn.spawn.html) to do something forever:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::{task, time}; // 1.3.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let forever = task::spawn(async {
        let mut interval = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(10));

        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            do_something().await;
        }
    });

    forever.await;
}
```

You can also use [`tokio::time::interval`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.3.0/tokio/time/fn.interval.html) to create a value that you can tick repeatedly. Perform the tick and call your function inside of the body of [`stream::unfold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/fn.unfold.html) to create a stream:

```rust
use futures::{stream, StreamExt}; // 0.3.13
use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use tokio::time; // 1.3.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let interval = time::interval(Duration::from_millis(10));

    let forever = stream::unfold(interval, |mut interval| async {
        interval.tick().await;
        do_something().await;
        Some(((), interval))
    });

    let now = Instant::now();
    forever.for_each(|_| async {}).await;
}

async fn do_something() {
    eprintln!("do_something");
}
```

See also:

- [How can I run a set of functions concurrently on a recurring interval without running the same function at the same time using Tokio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56273037/155423)

Comment: What does this even do: `for_each(|_| async {}).await;`

Comment: @EvanCarroll https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each

Comment: man that's confusing.. you can't do this with `.repeat`?

Comment: [`repeat`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/fn.repeat.html) says: *Create a stream which produces the same item repeatedly*, which doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Well, it would seem like I could create a stream of function pointers which sleeps for the interval and runs them, or create a stream a of functions pointers and stream of intervals and combine them and await or something.

Comment: Your second example does not run for ever. Can you modify this example to do that?

Comment: @EvanCarroll `forever.await` instead of the `timeout`.

Comment: I think we could demonstrate these two things substantially clearer if we reduced both to looping infinitely rather than 10 times and such, and dropped the elapsed calculation which isn't really relative to what you're trying to show. Just some points (i upvoted and marked this as chosen though). I also asked a follow up, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66898839/124486

Answer (score 4):

I am still a rust/tokio beginner, but I did find this solution helpful for myself:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time;
use tokio_stream::wrappers::IntervalStream;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = IntervalStream::new(time::interval(Duration::from_secs(1)));

    while let Some(_ts) = stream.next().await {
        println!("whelp, triggered again!");
    }
}
```

Please note that `_ts` holds the execution timestamp.

Comment: albeit this is a less general solution, it is more suitable for most cases of time-repeated streams in our codebase.